# Erro ao tentar logar usuario com mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou tentando logar um usuário ao meu sistema utilizando um banco MySql, mas está me retornando um erro de NullReference. Já tentei checar se era nulo antes de converter para string, mas o erro persiste. Por que o erro acontece? Como consertar?

Método onde executo a query:

```
private static string executarQueryScalar(MySqlCommand command)
{
    MySqlConnection connect = getConexão();
    try
    {
        connect.Open();
        return command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); //Linha do erro
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        connect.Close();
    }
}
```

Método onde eu o chamo:

```
private static bool testarLogin(string usuario, string senha)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE (usuario=@Usuario OR email=@Usuario) AND senha=@Senha";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, getConexão());
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", senha);

    return Convert.ToInt32(executarQueryScalar(command)) > 0;
}
```

Método getConexão():

```
private static MySqlConnection getConexão()
{
    string servidor = "server", banco = "database", banco_usuario = "user", banco_senha = "password";
    return new MySqlConnection($"Server={servidor};Database={banco};Uid={banco_usuario};Pwd={banco_senha}");
}
```

Erro apresentado:

> System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para
>   uma instância de um objeto.    em
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()    em
>   PureCheats.Validações.ChecarLogin.executarQueryScalar(MySqlCommand command)

Comment: A conexão tem que estar aberta antes da instancia de `new MySqlCommand(query, getConexão());`, e depois não há a necessidade de abrir novamente a conexão no método `executarQueryScalar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você está chamando o `getConexão()` fora do método que executa o comando, e depois chama novamente dentro do método. Assim, você passa o command com uma conexão, e abre outra.

Uma das formas corretas, seria algo assim:

```
private static bool testarLogin(string usuario, string senha)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conexao = getConexão())
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_usuario WHERE (usuario=@Usuario OR email=@Usuario) AND senha=@Senha";
        conexao.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, conexao );
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", usuario);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", senha);
        int resultado = command.ExecuteScalar();
        conexao.Close();

        return resultado > 0;
     }
}
```

ps. Sei que funciona com ã, mas confesso q me deu uma agonia ver a assinatura do método escrito assim. Procure sobre os padrões de nomenclatura =]

Comment: Bem, me incomoda mais ver um erro de português do que não estar dentro dos padrões de nomenclatura.

Comment: O mais importante eu esqueci de dizer: De qualquer forma, obrigado pela dica.